# How to un-translate a message translated with gettext?

Tags: python, gettext

I need to un-translate a message in python. My source is in English, I translate that string using `gettext`, say in French. I need to "return" to the original string in English. Is it possible in some way?

Here is why: I show some messages in a user interface, so messages needs to be translated. The same function logs that message in a db (debug intended). I want to store the message in the db in its original form (English).

An example:

```
alert_please( _("message to be shown and stored") )
```

and here the definition:

```
def alert_please(translated_message):
   show_the_message(translated_message)
   store_the_message(translated_message)
```

Fyi, I wouldn't translate the message in the `show_the_message` call because doing so I won't be able to look through the code to build the message catalog.

Comment: can you store the message before its translated?

Comment: Define your own `_()` function that builds a dictionary that maps the result of calling `gettext.gettext()` to the English source string (as well as returning that result as usual). This will allow you to write another function that uses this dictionary to un-do the translation.

Comment: @martineau you made my day. It works. Thank you!

Comment: @BendikKnapstad I could, but I would have a double call for every message...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @martineau I defined my own new `_()` function in this way:

```
reverse_dict = {}
def translate(msg_to_translate, get_ori=False):
    global reverse_dict

    if get_ori:
        return reverse_dict.get(msg_to_translate, msg_to_translate)

    translation = en.gettext(msg_to_translate)
    reverse_dict = {translation: msg_to_translate}

    return translation

import builtins
builtins.__dict__['_'] = translate
```

This call `_(msg)` just translate the message, the call `_(msg, True)` returns the original string. In my case I just store one single message: is enough, I log only the last one. The worst case is the return of the translated msg, not the original one.

Comment: Yes, that's basically what I was suggesting (and you're welcome). Overloading the `_()` function like that instead of having a two functions is clever. A possible improvement would be to implement things by defining a class with a similar `_()` _method_ because doing so would eliminate the need for a separate global variable to store the `reverse_dict`.